# Mosaic multiple 7gb TIFF into one big TIFF

Tags: python, raster, gdal, rasterio, envi

I have data of 10 sets each with 361 channels in format of ENVI.

Each set contain:

- 7gb format-less file (BSQ #UPDATE)
- 2.4gb .ENP file
- 9kb .HDR file

I try to mosaic all of them in one big file.

What I tried:

1. Used ENVI to mosaic all of them but it takes forever...
   Used different parameters to speed up the process but no help...
2. Tried rasterio, worked on small test set (used converted to tif files via ENVI).
   But it doesn't work with the full set, I think GDAL can't handle such big files.
3. ArcGIS Pro, the result end up messed up channels (the 361)

Comment: What are the requirements for the result? Do you have a favorite format? Does you use case require overviews/pyramid layers?

Comment: Do you mean BSQ/BIP/BIL with format-less file? Fastest way to make the images to appear as a one big image for GDAL is to do `gdalbuildvrt  mosaic.vrt *.bsq`. Virtual file can be converted further into other formats if needed.

Comment: I prefer to keep the meta data of the channels and CRS. The format is BSQ